# I would like to create a nxn matrix from two length n arrays using an addition function in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, append

I have two arrays n and k and I would like to create a matrix with the formula n + ik. I would like the matrix to have the following form;

```
n[0]+ik[0] n[0]+ik[1] n[0]+ik[2] etc. 
n[1]+ik[0] n[1]+ik[1] n[0]+ik[2] etc. 
etc.
```

so far I have;

```
z = 0 + 1j

for i,j in n
    for i,j in k 
    n_com = n + k*z
```

but I know that its not working, and I realise it doesnt really make any sense. Do I have to use append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code is clear

```
n = [1, 2, 3]
k = [4, 5, 6]
mat = []
for i in range(len(n)):
    row = []                # ready to make a row
    for j in range(len(k)):
        row.append(n[i] + 1j * k[j])
    mat.append(row)         # add the row to the mat
print(mat)                  # we get it
```

A more pythonic way would be (if you are interested)

```
mat = [[x + 1j * y for y in k] for x in n]
```

Further, many science people would use `numpy`, you may expect better performance and usability when matrix is large.

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array(n)
k = np.array(k).reshape((-1, 1))
mat = n + k.repeat(len(n), 1) * 1j
```

Comment: This is really good, but I seem to get a list.

when I do type(mat) it says list

I was thinking that I was going to get a nxn matrix, rather than a list of lists

Comment: but that is very helpful, I think I will be able to figure it out from here, cheers

Comment: Thanks! If you want to work with matrix I would really recommend numpy then :)